# Text captions on multiple Images with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new to jQuery so please be patient. I want to create a text caption that slides down on an image when you hover over a link on the page. I can do this when there's just one image with one caption but I have several images with different captions on one page.

I would like to create one function that can handle all of these in seperate instances and not create a function for each image/textcaption. The reason being is that the images and text is dynamic and changing in quantity overtime.

Please see an example of the code below, the .portText is a class of about 7 instances, when I hover over .moreInfo the text for every image slides down. I understand why this is happening, and I think I need to use ($this) somehow, but I also think i need to connect the picture to the text differently that it's done here. Hope this makes sense. Can anyone help? Cheers!

```
$(function() {

    $('.moreInfo').hover(

        function() {
        $('.portText').slideDown('slow');   
        },

        function() {
        $('.portText').slideUp('slow'); 
     }
     )
 });
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML markup that you have? It would be a lot easier to help you with what selectors you should use.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the element that was hovered over using `$(this)`.

The way I usually do this is to make `portText` a child of the `moreInfo` div:

```
<div class="moreInfo">
    <div class="portText">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

Then instead of just `$('.portText')` you can do `$('.portText', this)` (i.e. all portTexts that are children of the hovered element).

---

**Edit:** Another way to do it would be to use the data attribute and give each portText an ID:

```
<div class="moreInfo" data-id="1">....</div>

<div class="portText" id="portText-1">...</div>
```

Then for Javascript:

```
$('.moreInfo').hover(    
    function() {
        var myId= "#portText-" + $(this).data('id');
        $(myId).slideDown('slow');
    },

    function() {
        var myId= "#portText-" + $(this).data('id');
        $(myId).slideUp('slow');
    }
);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. That's definitely one way to do it and I may look into restructuring my html that way. It would be great to find away of doing it without changing the structure. Any other thoughts? Cheers.